# The app freeze after popViewControllerAnimated in iOS9

Tags: ios9, xcode7

My app edited from Spika app and it work fine before iOS9. But now I got a very serious issue in iOS9.

My app will freeze always after run `popViewControllerAnimated` or `dismissViewControllerAnimated` that view with `UITextField`, `UITextView` or `UISwitch`.
It's very strange and got no any error in Xcode Console.

I had try to create a new sample to test the operations in pop or dismiss view controller in iOS9 and it work fine. After I testing and I am sure it's a conflict with the libraries of spika app and iOS9 but I didn't know where is the problem.

Had anyone any idea to help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked through your project configuration to see how it all differs from the sample app?

Comment: If i had remove all the libraries and the core of Spika and it back to work. So the project configuration shall be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I finally had been resolved this issue.
In the `UIView+Extensions.m`  of spika

```
-(void) removeAllGestureRecognizers {    
    while (self.gestureRecognizers.count != 0) {
        [self removeGestureRecognizer:self.gestureRecognizers[0]];
    }    
}
```

This function cause the `UIView` freeze when leave one view in iOS9.
Thanks god or I will go crazy.